# fwrite function - Allow memory limit error

Tags: php, fwrite, large-files

I am trying to create stream from string and on 2 line I am getting error look like this

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24379392 bytes)

```
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, $response);
rewind($stream);
```

I am trying to get content of the large file from another host, and set in the local

Here is my logic.

```
$url = "https://webdav.abc.ru/abc/20/Storage/Files/c/c51256c25c0cb2610d5018df204b0135.mp4";
$method = "GET";
$headers = [];$body = null;
$response = $this->send(new HTTP\Request($method, $url, $headers, $body));
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, $response);
rewind($stream);
$response = $this->parseCurlResult($stream, $this->curlHandle);
```

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to get content of large file.

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by your PHP setting. Should be easy to fix if you have access to `php.ini`.

Adjust your memory limit (`memory_limit`) settings in `php.ini`.

**Example in php.ini:**

```
memory_limit=4096M
```

or

**In the file where you need a higher limit:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
```

Comment: this is a very bad suggestion , So I don't want to do changes in my php.ini file, I want to improve logic only

Comment: True that you can set it in php.int
You can also do it programmatically if you have different types of script or requests

Comment: php.ini and ini_set are the only options you have.

Comment: when I am trying to send large file  to another host the logic is working fine, but when I am trying to get same file , as a response I am getting error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ini_set("memory_limit", your-memory-limit-here)`
e.g

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M"); // your can also set a number of bytes parameter but it is easier to set a string indicating MB limit
```

Comment: this is a very bad suggestion , So I don't want to do changes in my php.ini file, I want to improve logic only

Comment: That depends on the amount of memory you have and what you anticipate the requirements will be. So in certain scenarios this will be a good and easy solution.